# Modeling yeast biochemical pathway using enzyme kinetics

Tags: bioinformatics, mathematical-models, database, enzyme-kinetics

I need enzyme concentration and metabolites concentration values to en-corporate these values in my model and do some simulation.

I searched through some database

yeast metabolome database http://www.ymdb.ca/
brenda and other enzyme databases for enzmye conc
and also did some literature search

but couldn't find much of data

where possibly i can get these data ??
is there any other way to do simulation without data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at SGD (the [Saccharomyces Genome Database](http://www.yeastgenome.org/)), and in particular [YeastCyc](http://pathway.yeastgenome.org/overviewsWeb/celOv.shtml). Some protein information pages at SGD give estimates of molecules per cell taken from [this Nature paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v425/n6959/pdf/nature02046.pdf).

***Added later in response to some comments:***

The question asks about levels of metabolites and of enzymes, not of transcripts. Microarray data can be, at best, only a guide to levels of proteins. Estimating the levels of metabolites from microarray data is a complete non-starter since there are entire layers of regulation that will be ignored. Just to give one example of a pitfall in this approach: you could have high levels of transcript from which you could you could infer high levels of enzyme, but that enzyme could be inactivated by a post-translational modification.

Comment: can't find much of data on YeastCyc and even

Comment: try approximating from microarray or RNAseq data.. they are available in [GEO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo) and [SRA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra)

Comment: Can you elaborate or cite a paper how to estimate concentration of metabolites mainly present in  this pathway[ubiquinone synthesis](http://pathway.yeastgenome.org/YEAST/NEW-IMAGE?type=PATHWAY&object=PWY3O-862&detail-level=1) from microarray RNAseq data. If any body have done similar thing and documented it please let me know.